# Canvas Placement Issue

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas which is 500*250 (w*h) and applied this code to it;

```
var cvs = document.getElementById('Dugong');
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');
var cvsHeight = cvs.height; // 250
var cvsWidth = cvs.width; // 500

var loadUpFlappy = "Flappy";
var loadUpDugong = "Dugong";

ctx.fillStyle = "#ECA20F";
ctx.fillRect(5, (cvsHeight / 2) + 1, ctx.measureText(loadUpFlappy).width + 10, 2); // across, down, width, height
ctx.fillRect(cvsWidth - (ctx.measureText(loadUpDugong).width + 5), cvsHeight / 2 + 1, ctx.measureText(loadUpDugong).width + 10, 2);

ctx.fillStyle = "#DADFE1";
ctx.font = "40px Century Schoolbook";
ctx.fillText(loadUpFlappy, 10, cvsHeight / 2);
ctx.fillText(loadUpDugong, cvsWidth - (ctx.measureText(loadUpDugong).width + 10), cvsHeight / 2);
```

To my knowledge, this code should ouput;

1. One `#ECA20F` line which has a height of `2`, is `5` away from the **left** canvas border, is `1` below the canvas middle line and has the width of `Flappy` plus `10`.
2. Another `#ECA20F` line which has a height of `2`, is `5` away from the **right** canvas border, is `1` below the canvas middle line and has the width of `Dugong` plus `10`.

AND

1. The word `Flappy` in `#DADFE1` which is `10` away from the **left** border of the canvas and is in the middle the canvas.
2. The word `Dugong` also in `#DADFE1` which is `10` away from the **right** border of the canvas and is also in the middle of the canvas.

---

My problem is that the lines are not matching up with the text (they should span the width of the text plus 5px on either side). Instead they do this;

- [View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mzct.jpg)

Sorry if there are any glaringly obvious answers to this issue as I am a 'noob' when it comes to javascript and canvases.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I thought that it'd not be possible to take the text length. So I'm a bit wrong.

---

There's no easy way to place the lines because you don't know the font size in the text. What you can do is to align the text in center (`ctx.textAlign = 'center'`) and place it on a certain point which will be its center. Then you set the line width according to the text length and size. Put the line always below to this point and set the same X as the point, subtracting it with the width you got for the line divided by 2. But the line width wouldn't be exact in this case, but it helps smaller words.

Comment: Your comment made me realise that if I declared the font style **before** testing for the width, rather than **after** it'd work. And luckily, it did!
So thanks I guess.